# having problem to shift into GUI from virtual terminal

Tags: 18.04

I purged python3 due to some problems. After doing that, it removed a lot of packages.I installed Firefox and visual studio then I restarted the laptop but it switch into the virtual terminal. I searched many times but could not find the solution. I tried `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` but it shows

```
package have unmet dependencies , and unable to correct problem, you held broken package
```

Please help me I am in trouble.

Comment: If you did remove `python3`, quite a lot of built-in Ubuntu tools will no longer work, so repairs will be very manual (eg. `dpkg` will work, but you may find `apt` and like front ends that sit above & automate download & install via `dpkg` no longer work). The obvious first step is `sudo apt -f install` but I suspect you'll keep finding normal fix tools don't work as needed unless `python3-minimal` is installed.  A re-install may be a faster fix

Answer (score 0):

Since python3 is a requirement for almost anything in Ubuntu I would advice to reinstall your system. You can do that WITHOUT picking the format option in the "something else" part of setting up partitions. Only mount your partitions. It will overwrite all system related files and packages but leave your personal files alone.

Mind to make sure the backups you have can be restored before attempting this. In case you pick the wrong setup during the re-install.